# simplexml encoding issue

Tags: php, xml, encoding, simplexml

I'm not really sure if this is an encoding problem or what, but I have a problem using simple xml with some of the characters in the text

```
$xml = <<<HOHOHO
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-2" standalone="yes"?>
<videos>
    <video>
    <ContentProvider>bl abla</ContentProvider>
    <ArtistName>T-Boz</ArtistName>
    <CopyrightLine>(C)2009 SME Espa&#xF1;a, S.</CopyrightLine>
    </video>
</videos>
HOHOHO;

$a = simplexml_load_string ($xml);

foreach ( $a->video as $new ) 
    die($new->CopyrightLine);
```

The thing is that the ñ character gets all messed up and becomes something like Ăą, when it should be a ñ.
I find it strange simplexml changes this to a character anyway instead of just keeping it as it is...

I know that this has to do something with hex codes but I haven't found a solution yet

Things I've tried so far:
converting the string to iso-8859-2 with mb_convert_string,
converting the string to utf-8 with mb_convert_string,
converting with html_entity_decode,
converting with html_special chars

all of above attempts either failed to parse xml or just didn't fix the character

Help would me very appreciated!

Comment: Do you need to use `iso-8859-2`? Did you tried how it works with `utf-8`?

Comment: I had once this issue while coding with notepad under windows and it was because of the file encoding, it was ANSI instead of UTF-8

Comment: it's linux
Also, I've just tried utf-8 and it's the same... in the url you sent I get identical results also...

Answer (score 5):

The problem you have is not the input string, but the output string. SimpleXML uses UTF-8 internally, and if you request a string from the SimpleXMLElement, you will get the string encoded as UTF-8.

```
$output = (string) $new->CopyrightLine; # will always be UTF-8 encoded
```

So you need to the re-encoding with the output, not the input.

Compare with this [code example and output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/10Irsp), that is displayed as UTF-8 while the input is your input.

There is no way around this btw, because SimpleXML will always give you UTF-8 encoded strings.

Comment: Looks promising but the code you pasted doesn't do anything.. character still all messed up.

Comment: The bespoken re-encoding of `$output` is not part of the code in my answer and not on code-pad viper. You need to encode `$output` from UTF-8 to your target charset on your own. You have not given any target charset, so probably you can more specifically tell in which charset the output should be and which libraries you have available for re-encoding (iconv?).

Comment: I'd preferably like it to be UTF-8... but nor utf8_encode or iconv do it for me... :/ I don't know :/

Comment: If you like to have UTF-8 I have great news for you: you don't need to re-encode anything from SimpleXML. However you might want to tell your browser that what you pass to it *is* UTF-8 encoded, see http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-changing-encoding especially Step 2

Comment: I didn't want to get in details from the start but here's the thing...  I have an original xml file that I'm rewriting to another xml file. And the original has the &#xF1; in. That's exactly what I want also in the new xml file... but don't know how to do it :/

Comment: The thing is also that I'm working in terminal and if I cat the original file I get &#xF1; but it I cat the file that went through simplexml it has the dodgy characters :S

Comment: okay, that's actually *useful* context to your problem because it explains more clearly what you see as an issue. Let's continue in chat.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6532/discussion-between-hakre-and-tadej-magajna)